# Do any wireframing tools support keyboard control for accessibility testing?

Tags: accessibility, keyboard, wireframe

I have some keyboard interactions that I want to test, namely the use of a new sortable card component that I want to make keyboard accessible. The problem is that I use Balsamiq and there is no way of simulating what should happen when a keyboard user tabs through the controls to the card stack. **Are there any wireframing tools that can simulate the act of tabbing through controls?** I'm at the point where I think I may need to build the interface in HTML to just simulate the interactions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate the tabbing order in the Axure Design tool (it is a bit similar to Balsamiq) because you have a variety of states you can utilise to simulate all sorts of behaviour, e.g. onclick, onSelected, onUnselected, onFocus, onLostFocus, onKeyDown, onKeyUp, etc.

Comment: Like any tool it does come with a learning curve, but their website has excellent resources to help you get to grips with it.